# CSS: SVG rotation animation fail

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

Im trying to rotate blades from it's centre, as a windmill does, I'm new in CSS and I can't make it to spin properly, blades dissapear from the screen. Actually it is not working in some browser, for example in firefox for pc, but it works on safari for OSx an in every Ios browsers. I've pasted the SVG below, but here is my code complete: http://codepen.io/DavidKartF1/pen/mVKwpX

```
<svg
class="windmill-icon"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
viewBox="0 0 100 100"
>

<g transform="translate(0,-952.36217)">
    <g id="rotor" style="transform-origin: 48.327% 62.24%; transform: rotate(0deg);">
        <path style="" d="m 52.032964,981.03514 c -1.255809,0.0277 -2.456062,0.72451 -3.071613,1.91975 -0.895349,1.73855 -0.212098,3.8744 1.526442,4.76975 1.738541,0.89534 3.874394,0.21209 4.769741,-1.52645 0.895349,-1.73854 0.212099,-3.87439 -1.526442,-4.76974 -0.543294,-0.27979 -1.127305,-0.40591 -1.698128,-0.39331 z" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
        <path style="" d="m 56.334032,984.98211 c -0.04983,0.52212 -0.197859,1.04165 -0.452665,1.53642 -0.235879,0.45802 -0.543385,0.85701 -0.902025,1.18618 1.155573,1.33508 3.100732,3.52774 3.660967,3.81626 0.776522,0.39991 11.183654,3.80654 14.660386,4.60925 2.124798,0.49057 7.324796,1.52986 7.794423,0.51214 0.07685,-0.16654 0.02896,-0.38934 -0.181727,-0.67735 -0.588843,-0.80495 -5.351732,-3.30398 -5.65996,-3.46272 -11.276895,-5.95922 -16.673816,-7.27268 -18.919399,-7.52018 z" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
        <path style="" d="m 48.100161,953.54009 c -0.182674,0.0167 -0.35154,0.17246 -0.495619,0.49892 -0.402687,0.91243 -0.188457,6.28177 -0.171813,6.62807 0.470537,12.55703 1.99393,17.91869 2.907627,20.05272 0.955097,-0.43748 2.060996,-0.51848 3.10257,-0.17182 0.580003,-1.67633 1.476988,-4.37943 1.447205,-4.99913 -0.04193,-0.87245 -2.290657,-11.59173 -3.333859,-15.00402 -0.637549,-2.08542 -2.339769,-7.10702 -3.456111,-7.00474 z" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
        <path style="" d="m 47.908522,985.18366 c -1.716128,0.32806 -4.713996,0.93611 -5.256858,1.28531 -0.734592,0.47253 -8.892997,7.78187 -11.326528,10.39146 -1.730618,1.85582 -6.183724,6.94777 -3.660966,6.67437 0.991531,-0.1075 5.536887,-2.9778 5.828469,-3.1654 10.611197,-6.66826 14.501935,-10.66451 15.902737,-12.52922 -0.819752,-0.68079 -1.33845,-1.63622 -1.486854,-2.65652 z" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
    </g>
    <g id="stick">
        <path style="" d="m 50.751702,993.03361 2.605442,0 1.172837,58.64579 -5.286594,0 z" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
        <path style="" d="m 50.755774,988.66999 0,2.99716 2.642451,0 0,-2.98178 c -0.851509,0.19175 -1.762006,0.19601 -2.642451,-0.0154 z" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
        <path style="" d="m 50.102459,991.89764 c -0.07744,0 -0.138774,0.1601 -0.138774,0.35684 l 0,0.19164 c 0,0.19675 0.06134,0.35685 0.138774,0.35685 l 3.951729,0 c 0.07743,0 0.138773,-0.1601 0.138773,-0.35685 l 0,-0.19164 c 0,-0.19674 -0.06134,-0.35684 -0.138773,-0.35684 l -3.951729,0 z m 3.9286,0.0463 0.0099,0 c 0.0022,0 0.07599,0.14429 0.07599,0.3205 l 0,0.17181 c 0,0.1762 -0.07053,0.3172 -0.07269,0.3172 l -0.01322,0 c 0.01737,-0.075 0.03635,-0.17784 0.03635,-0.29077 l 0,-0.22798 c 0,-0.11431 -0.01817,-0.21549 -0.03635,-0.29076 z" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
    </g>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to finding the rotor's center with `transform-origin`, and how `48.327% 62.24%` should be interpreted when the rotor is drawn around coordinates ~(50,1000) and then hoisted 952px by its parent `<g>`. You can read about the SVG coordinate system and how it affects `transform`s here:

https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-transformations/

A solution to your problem that at least works in both Firefox and Chrome is to use pixel values instead of percentages:

```
.windmill-icon #rotor {
    transform-origin: 52px 985px;
    ...
}
```

Updated pen (note that I have removed the rotor's `style` attribute and moved everything to CSS): http://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/adKVqZ

Answer (score 0):

Read that guide >> [SVG animation](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/).
It helps me few months ago :).
Basicly, its better to animate from inside of element, then from css.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <rect x="10" y="10" height="110" width="110"
         style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff">

        <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform"
            begin="0s"
            dur="20s"
            type="rotate"
            from="0 60 60"
            to="360 60 60"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
        />
    </rect>

</svg>
```